# Back to back parentheses in Python

Tags: python, syntax

I am watching a video and saw the following line of code:

```
encoded_frames = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
```

Can someone please tell me what the "(cnn)(video)" part is doing? Is the `(video)` part an anonymous function being called?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, TimeDistributed appears to be callable (i.e. implements the `__call__` method) and the second pair of parenthesis holds the arguments for the call to `__call__`

```
class Test:
def __init__(self, var):
    self.var = var

def one(self):
    print("running one")

def __call__(self, v):
    print("v: " + v)
    self.one()
    return "self.var: " + self.var

print(Test("1")("run"))
```

This yields

```
v: run
running one
self.var: 1
```

Test("1") instantiates the Test object with the self.var value of "1", the ("run") imediately calls `__call__` on the instance and passes "run" as a parameter to the `__call__` method.

You can have similar constructs in other cases as well, e.g. if you access a callable object in a dict

```
def bla(v):
    return "in bla: " + v

d = {'func': bla}

print(d.get('func')('something')) # in bla: something
```

Answer (score 0):

The class in question has `__call__` method that allows to treat it's instances as functions.

To see exactly what happens in your specific case, you can have a look on official github of Keras ([Layer class](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1d2ad790dd43a2d702176c1170b2f3fd592a385a/keras/engine/topology.py), [TimeDistributed](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1d2ad790dd43a2d702176c1170b2f3fd592a385a/keras/layers/wrappers.py)). Your class in question is ingerited like that: `TimeDistributed  <- Wrapper <- Layer`. In `Layer.__call__` we see that it's a wrapper around `.call` method, so here you go.